# Clever calculation of the adjugate of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to calculate $\text{adj}({A})$ the adjugate of a square matrix $A$. Matrix $A$ is singular. Is there a clever way of doing so, instead of the direct approach which is computationally expensive?

If $A$ was invertible, then one could calculate the inverse $A^{-1}$, and the adjugate would be

$ \text{adj}(A) = A^{-1} \det(A) $

But here, $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Adjoint is an archaic term, nowadays this is called the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).

Comment: Also what do you mean "just take the inverse"? Are you concerned with algorithmic complexity?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, then I think the simplest and most efficient way to compute the adjugate would be by computing the inverse using Gauss-Jordan elimination, and then multiplying by the determinant of $A$.  If there is a better way, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: Yes.  It does.  Thank you @AnneBauval